# How to set a one-to-many relationship in greenDAO?

Tags: android, one-to-many, greendao

hope you have a good day.

I am new to greenDAO, and am wondering how to model a one-to-many relationship using greenDAO in an Android app so that I can retrieve a list of TestResult entities that belong to a User entity. I've used the @ToMany annotation at the User entity class and @ToOne at TestResult, following [this](https://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities) documentation. However, even after persisting TestResult entity objects with the User property set, retrieving the same User causes a null error for its list of TestResult entity objects.

I would be greatly appreciate it if you guys would be so gracious as to to provide some help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id private Long id;
 
    @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "customerId")
    @OrderBy("date ASC")
    private List<Order> orders;
}
 
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id private Long id;
    private Date date;
    private long customerId;
}
```

Customer and Order are two entities. One customer have multiple orders. For this customerId is in order entity.

> private long customerId;

In customer Entity,

```
 @ToMany(referencedJoinProperty = "customerId")
  @OrderBy("date ASC")
  private List<Order> orders;
```

Reference
[for details](https://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/)

Comment: Just to confirm, Customer and Order are in different files right? If yes, then I have done something similar but for example when persisting a few TestResult objects with the userID set I am not able to get a list of TestResult entities that belong to a User. The debugger always show the list of TestResults of the Customer are null.

Comment: Yes both are separate files. Please share your code files. Let me look into it

Comment: Hi, here is the link to my entity classes and MainActivity file https://drive.google.com/file/d/13El3z1b_z1ddfVkRPscl_iMH8pYO1eP9/view?usp=sharing,%20

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q0q_RU7CfbU4ceGlLpFMviJjgKsiXbQU/view?usp=sharing,%20

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Urvvd1NbRyqRm1oW8hLuso71BSNYAAo4/view?usp=sharing